# Height/width definitions of <a>tag was not implemented

Tags: html, css

First, see fiddle [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bs8N5/1/)

I created a list

```
<div id="info_list">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The css of  tag is

```
#info_list ul li a{
    height: 30px;
    width: 230px;
    color: #AAA;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

However, even I regulated the height and the width, I still cannot reach the url by clicking the space place of each list. It only works by clicking the text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`height` and `width` do not apply to non-floating elements that are `display: inline`, which `<a>` elements are by default.

Change the `display` value to `block` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
display: inline-block
```

to CSS, I think that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I often like to use the technique of a "link spanner". It lets you make the link container whatever size you want and the link spanner will expand to make anchor fit your height/width definitions.

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duAT7/5/

```
<ul>
<li class="container">
    text
<a href="https://www.google.com">
   <span class="link-spanner"></span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="container">
    text
<a href="https://www.google.com">
   <span class="link-spanner"></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>


.container{
  height: 30px;
  background: #2C2B29;
  padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:white;
  /*Important:*/
  position:relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/*Important:*/
.link-spanner{
  position:absolute; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#info_list ul li a{
    height: 30px;
    width: 230px;
    color: #AAA;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
}
```

please add css tage display:block in your css defination.